# MySQL getting result from 2 different tables by comparing two different criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

It's me again with my weird queries.

```
table users:

id | type | partner | company
------------------------------
 1 |   2  |   0     | comp1
 2 |   3  |   2     | comp2
 3 |   3  |   2     | comp3
 4 |   3  |   3     | comp4

table orders:

id | user | partner
--------------------
 1 |  2   |   2
 2 |  2   |   2
 3 |  2   |   3
 4 |  3   |   2
```

I know it's a little hart to keep track of all these numbers. 
I'm logged in as `type 2`(users table) and want to get listed all information from the `orders` table from the `users` with `type 3` and which are listed as my `partners (partner 2)` in addition I want the `company` name from the `users` `table` also in my results.
The query will be excecuted on the `orders` table.

```
result:

id | user | partner | company
------------------------------
 1 |  2   |   2     | comp2
 2 |  2   |   2     | comp2
 4 |  3   |   2     | comp3
```

Thanks in advance and ask me if you don't understand the problem. I will try to explain better and any edits to make it more clear are also welcomed.

Comment: what is relation between this two tables, i mean the key

Comment: this is the problem. the only relation between the two tables is id from users table to user from orders table.

Comment: but there is no primary key defined on the tables

Comment: in users table and orders table the first fields are AI

Comment: can u check my answer

Comment: Given the answers you've received previously, you're now in a position to ask better questions. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I'm wondering if you actually own this place.You can have opinions,about people asking questions and criticise them.But telling someone your critics is different from being rude and unrespectful to someone you don't even know.Here's the deal,I think more about what I ask, which is a simple task for me and you go and learn how to respect people and try to tell them your critics in a helpful way, which I bet isn't that easy for you to change. Learn some manners.The world doesn't begin on SO and doesn't end here.I can ask somewhere else,but how far will u go with this low personality?

Comment: I wish I owned this place; that would be amazing. Unfortunately, the sum total of my engagement with SO amounts to providing answers where adequate information is provided (and that fit within the very limited confines of my knowledge), and advising where and how I think questions could be improved.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this

```
select s.id,
        case when src = 'u' then s.users
        else s.partner
        end as users,
        case when src = 'p' then s.users
        else s.partner
        end as partner,
        u.company
    from
   (
   select 'u' as src,id,users,partner from o where users = 2 and (users = partner)
   union
    select 'p',id,partner,users from o where partner = 2 and (users <> partner)
    ) s
    join u on u.id = s.partner
    where type = 3;
```

Hopefully self explanatory, note I only need to know the user, the query figures out the partners.

result

```
+------+-------+---------+---------+
| id   | users | partner | company |
+------+-------+---------+---------+
|    2 |     2 |       2 | comp2   |
|    1 |     2 |       2 | comp2   |
|    4 |     3 |       2 | comp3   |
+------+-------+---------+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```